# Individual column searching not working with DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like to create a table with the jQuery DataTables plugin. My table is supposed to have individual column searching but my code doesn't work. I checked [this](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html) example:

```
var tableVol = $('#tableVolToDo');

tableVol
    .DataTable({
        "language": {
            "url": "http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/French.json"
        },
        "lengthMenu": [50, 100, 200]
    })
    .columns().every(function () { // Apply the search
        var that = this;
        $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
            if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                that
                .search(this.value)
                .draw();
            }
        });
    });
// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
$('#tableVolToDo tfoot th').each(function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
});
```

Comment: Would you post your HTML and source data sample as well?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ezY5Sh21